# How to collect traffic data and macroscopic statistics in Veins?

Tags: omnet++

Hello StackEx community.

I am implementing certain scenarios in Veins 3.0 and I wish to collect certain traffic statistics such as the Average Waiting Time, the Average Energy consumption, etc from my simulation.

Please help on how to generate and interpret these information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`TraCIMobility` already records some statistics that you can directly use or build on. See, for example [totalCO2Emission](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-3.0/src/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIMobility.cc#L73). Other statistics you might have to implement yourself, e.g., after [detecting that a car was stopped for a certain time](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-3.0/src/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc#L88). See the [OMNeT++ user manual pages on result recording and analysis](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#cha:analyzing-simulation-results) for general information on how to do that and the [Tic Toc tutorial](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial/) for a concrete example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sir. I have a simple query. This process is taken every `step` times, right? So I need to implement something that would account for each step of the simulation, correct? How do I get these variable values into a, say, text file then?
Also, the car is assumed to be stopped for `speed = -1`, doesn't it?
Thanks.

Comment: The `TraCIMobility` module already keeps track of how long a car was driving (`totalTime` and `totalDistance`). For converting from OMNeT++'s output format to other file formats, see the documentation on its `scavetool`. Note that you can also directly load the results into GNU R, using an import library provided by OMNeT++. Either way is documented in the manual.

Comment: Sir. I wrote an `add.xml` file for SUMO to record the edge-based stats that I require in my scenario. I ran the scenario independently on SUMO and found that data is indeed being recorded. But when I ran it in Veins, no data was recorded. Does `TraCI` disable data collection on SUMO side during a run in Veins? How do I get around?

Thanks.

Comment: You most likely ran SUMO via sumo-launchd.py, which creates a temporary copy of your scenario (in /tmp). After the scenario ran, the copy is deleted. This means, if you are logging to the directory that the SUMO simulation is executing in, your logged data will be cleaned along with the temporary copy.

Comment: Sir, I used an absolute path to store the file, which is now being generated. But in the output, I am getting only the configuration being printed and not the statistics as it ought to be. Whereas SUMO does output the statistics to the file. Is this behaviour normal?

Comment: A reason might be that SUMO dumps the data to the files once the simulation terminate normally. But in case of Veins, TraCI explicitly requests the termination, which might be deemed abnormal termination by SUMO, thus prohibiting dump of data. Is there a way I can still cause SUMO to dump the data?