# Omnet++- Energy consumption curves

Tags: omnet++, energy

I'm doing network simulation using Omnet ++ software and castalia. so i want to know how to plot power consumption, RSSI value curves
thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. please read guidelines on posting new questions. Also describe what have you tried so far and add minimum working example wherever required.

Comment: Hi, I use castalia imported in Omnet++.  I want to know how to plot energy consumption by each node in the network.

Comment: You have to be more clear about the graphs you want to plot. Are you talking about two graphs? One being about power consumption, and the other being RSSI?  What is the dependent variable for each of the graphs?

Answer (score 0):

This question's answer is dependent on what software you're using exactly. OMNeT++ provides a suite and toolchain for visualization, but as user [Thanassis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3811292/thanassis) points out below, Catalia has its' own specialized evaluation tools.

### For general OMNeT++ simulations

The [OMNeT++ tutorial](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial/part5.html) covers this in quite a lot of detail. Basically:

- tell OMNeT++ what data you're recording (by editing the `.ned` files) using the `@statistic` annotation
- modify the simulation to track the data you're interested in, either over simulation time (referred to as vectors) or per simulation (referred to as scalars), basically using `emit()`.
- make sure that your simulation (`omnetpp.ini`) is set up to collect the statistics (by setting e.g. histogram or vector as the type of collected data)
- use either the graphical OMNeT++ interface or your own scripts to analyze the output of the simulation (which is, by default, stored in a folder called `results` wherever you're running the simulation, unless you change that in the `omnetpp.ini`)

Please also refer to these related questions:

- [How to collect traffic data and macroscopic statistics in Veins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051936/how-to-collect-traffic-data-and-macroscopic-statistics-in-veins)
- [Calculating end-to-end delay for SimpleServerApp in Veins-LTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818192/calculating-end-to-end-delay-for-simpleserverapp-in-veins-lte)

Comment: Even though Castalia is based on OMNeT, the way we draw graphs and collect output does not follow OMNeT's paradigm. So I would not suggest to follow OMNeT's tutorial. Unfortunately the OP is not clear on what exactly they want, so it's hard to suggest concrete actions.

Comment: @thanassis are there any specific differences? I've never used castalia, I just assumed it would use the same mechanisms that omnet provides :)

Comment: Castalia does not follow OMNeT's output collecting mechanisms. Because of the need to aggregate and slice data in custom ways we went with a custom mechanism, **completely separate** to OMNeTs. Mind you these decisions were taken many years ago, when OMNeT 4.x was the current version. Castalia has not been ported to OMNeT 5.x.